# jquery jpicker is being cut off by top of browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jpicker and it's being cut off by the browser. Has anyone ever experienced this problem before?

Here's my jquery snippet

```
//jpicker hex color picker
if($('#hexPicker').length) {
    $('#hexPicker').jPicker();
}
```

Here's my form snippet

```
<div class="row"> 
    <label for="color">Background Color</label>
    <input type="text" name="color" value="00ff00" class="small" id="hexPicker"  /> 
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Once I used one color picker and faced the same kind of problem and I can remember that I used chrome's element inspection tool to find out the equivalent css style of the container and I could successfully changed the css style of the container. You may try this approach to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but you may try this

```
$('#hexPicker').jPicker({
  window: {
    position: {
      x: 'screenCenter', // acceptable values "left", "center", "right", "screenCenter", or relative px value
      y: 'center', // acceptable values "top", "bottom", "center", or relative px value
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I believe it's {window:{position:{x:'screenCenter',y:'center'}}}. Anyway, the y value is relative to the element that expands the jPicker (not screen-absolute), so if that is scrolled near the top of the page, it still appears cut off.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using jqueryui tabs and the positioning is a reported bug but using

`window:{position:{x:'screenCenter',y:'200'}} // 200 can be any fixed value`

Setting an explicit value solved the problem for me and thought it was worth sharing